Pulling labels for def defined functions from a list of strings in python
I would like to create functions using the normal def procedure in Python with labels assigned to the namespace that are pulled from a list of strings. How can this be achieved?
An example problem: given an arbitrary list of strings exampleList=['label1','label2','label3',...] of length k, initialize k def defined functions of the form
exampleList=['label1','label2','label3','label4']
def label1(arg: str):
    if len(arg)>exampleList[0]
        print('the word '+arg+' has more letters than the word '+exampleList[0])
def label2(arg: str):
    if len(arg)>exampleList[1]
        print('the word '+arg+' has more letters than the word '+exampleList[1])
# ...etc.

programmatically.
If the functions to be defined only involve operations implementable within lambda functions, then this can be done with lambda functions by updating the globals() dict. E.g., one can write something like
exampleList=['label1','label2','label3']
exampleOperation= lambda j,k: len(j)-len(k)
globals().update(zip(exampleList,[lambda k:exampleOperation(j,k) for j in exampleList]))

The above example initialized some lambda functions with labels assigned from the list exampleList. I would, however, like to accomplish the analogous task with normal def defined functions rather than lambda functions.

you could use a class with a factory function
class MyLabels:

    def __init__(self, label_list):
        for label in label_list:
            setattr(self, label, self.label_factory(label))

    def label_factory(self, label):
        def my_func(arg: str):
            if len(arg) > len(label):
                print(f'the word {arg} has more letters than the word {label}')
        return my_func

exampleList=['label1','label2','label3','label4']
ml = MyLabels(exampleList)
ml.label1('stackoverflow') #the word stackoverflow has more letters than the word label1

